# How do I create a dropdown list for a column of constantly-changing values in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel spreadsheet with a column for years, with a header:

```
Years
1993
1993
1994
1994
1994
...
2011
2011
```

There are duplicate values for the years, and additional rows will be added over time.

I have another cell that needs to show a dropdown list for the years, but only the unique years. I've tried using the data validation feature in Excel 2011, but it has 2 issues:

1. It displays the duplicate years.
2. I tell it to use the entire column, and it includes the empty cells in the dropdown list.

How do I get a dropdown list of years that will display only unique values, while automatically updating as additional rows are added?

**Edit**: a little more information. The dropdown list is used in a separate sheet to display calculated data, like an Access form. The user can pick a year range and the data will update accordingly. The original sheet is just a list of all the data.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of validations, I use VBA + one dirty trick:

First, enter VBA editor with Alt+F11
Then, I put my "Dynamic List Validation Code" (tm) :) in the respective worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal rTarget As Excel.Range)

On Error GoTo noVal

With rTarget.Validation
    .Modify xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, Excel.Evaluate(.ErrorTitle)
End With

noVal:

End Sub
```

This code updates the cell validation list with the list generated by the formula entered in Data->Validation->Error Message->Title. This way, each cell with list validation
can have its own formula.

Then, I add a module (Insert->Module) and then put this code in the new module:

```
Function GenDynList(rRng As Range)

sRet = ""

For Each rCell In rRng
    If Not IsEmpty(rCell.Value) And InStr(sRet, rCell.Value) = 0 Then
        sRet = sRet & "," & rCell.Value
    End If
Next

GenDynList = Mid(sRet, 2)

End Function
```

This function returns all the cells in the range without blanks or repetitions.
Then, in each cell with list validation, I add GenDynList(range) in the
Error Message title of data validation.

Answer (score 0):

Messy. There's no built-in way to do that that automatically updates. It would be simpler to just create a separate list with all the possible years that you could be interested in rather than trying to limit it to those in your data set.

Comment: Problem is, Years is only one of the columns. I also have a country, state, district, and type. The list of all possible values in these columns, unlike years, will be unknown until we get new the new set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Pivot Table from the data on another sheet. Use Years as rows, the rest of the table is irrelevant. Sort and filter the rows as required (eg explicitly filter OUT "[blank]"). Make the cells where the row labels are into the target of your data validation.

Use an expanding named range to always use all the new labels:
http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm

Repeat for other columns such as country, state etc. If you base all the pivots off the same data range they will all refresh together when you refresh any one of them. Your process will now be: add new data, refresh pivots, use updated data validation.

Further thoughts: Using a table for the source data will make it easy to update the Pivot Tables since they will always use the whole table. Alternatively use an expanding named range as the data source to avoid issues when you add more rows.

Note that you can use a range from a different worksheet as a source for data validation if you do this by defining a named range. You can't use a normal range explicitly referring to another sheet.